# notification views not showing already marked checked boxes

Tags: php

```
 <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Notification Views</label>
                                    <div class="controls">

                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="1" <? if (in_array("1", $arr))
                                                    {?>checked="checked"<?}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Teachers
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="2" <? if (in_array("2", $arr))
                                                    {?>checked="checked"<?}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Parents
                                        </label>
                                        <br>
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="3" <? if (in_array("3", $arr))
                                                    {?>checked="checked"<?}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Management
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="4" <? if (in_array("4", $arr))
                                                    {?>checked="checked"<?}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Office
                                        </label>
                                        <?php echo form_error('n_index'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Here is my code,and the check box is not not showing the selected value. How i get the selected item in checkbox.please help someone.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not showing the selected value'? And what is the property of `$arr`

Answer (score 1):

You have error in PHP syntax. Use echo to make checked

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Notification Views</label>
<div class="controls">

    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="1" <?php if (in_array("1", $arr))
                {echo 'checked="checked"';}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Teachers
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="2" <?php if (in_array("2", $arr))
                {echo 'checked="checked"';}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Parents
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="3" <?php if (in_array("3", $arr))
                {echo 'checked="checked"';}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Management
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="4" <?php if (in_array("4", $arr))
                {echo 'checked="checked"';}?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Office
    </label>
<?php echo form_error('n_index'); ?>                                      
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a PHP syntax error, simply try this:

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="n_index[]" value="1" <?php if(in_array(1,$arr)) echo 'checked="checked"'?> class="a1" title="Choose"> Teachers
</label>
```

Do this for rest of the three, and it will solve your issue.